# Prove geometric realizations are homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces

I am solving the following problem:

Let $(\Gamma_1, I)$ and $(\Gamma_2, I)$ be isomorphic graphs, then $|\Gamma_1|_I$ and $|\Gamma_2|_I$ are homeomorphic.

We denote by $(\Gamma, I)$  a graph, and  its geometric realization by $|\Gamma|_I$.

The definitions is given in the [lecture note](https://math.unice.fr/%7Elabourie/preprints/pdf/surfaces.pdf) Page 12, Definition: 2.2.1.

$\textbf{Added}$: A graph isomorphism $\phi= (\alpha, \beta)$ between two graph $\Gamma_1 = (V_1, E_1, i_1)$ and $\Gamma = (V_2, E_2, i_2)$ is a pair of bijective maps $\alpha: V_1 \rightarrow V_2$ and $\beta: E_1 \rightarrow E_2$ such that the following diagram commutes:

[image]

To solve the above problem, my approach is to prove that the following diagram commutes. [image]

Please help me.

Comment: You should add the definition of an isomorphism of graphs.

Comment: @PaulFrost I have added the definition.

Comment: Your definition of isomorphism deals with **oriented graphs**. You need one for (non-oriented) graphs. Certainly you have to require that $\phi$ is compatible with the involutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The precise definition and contextual background to "geometric realisation" varies. But all you need to know is that geometric realisation is a **functor**. Two isomorphic graphs are related by morphisms of graphs: say, $f:\Gamma_1\to\Gamma_2$ is one such morphism. Then you have a continuous map $|f|:|\Gamma_1|\to|\Gamma_2|$.

If $g:\Gamma_2\to\Gamma_1$ is the inverse, so that $gf=\mathrm{Id}_{\Gamma_1}$ and $fg=\mathrm{Id}_{\Gamma_2}$, then $|g|:|\Gamma_2|\to|\Gamma_1|$ is continuous and we also know that $|g|\circ|f|=|gf|=|\mathrm{Id}_{\Gamma_1}|=\mathrm{Id}_{|\Gamma_1|}$ using the functorial property. Similarly, $|f|\circ|g|$ is also the identity.

So that's two continuous maps which are mutually inverse: the spaces $|\Gamma_1|$ and $|\Gamma_2|$ are then homeomorphic, by definition.

General fact: *functors preserve isomorphisms*.

Note: I have said $|\cdot|$ is a functor, but you have not provided a precise definition of your category of graphs. I just assume you are working with a sensible definition of that and of $|\cdot|$ so that we have the functorial property.

Definitions vary. One such definition is given [here](https://kerodon.net/tag/001D), and this definition is nice because our geometric realisation functor can be taken to be the standard one for simplicial sets.